# how to wrap non collection property in xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I know this question was asked before, but still no response to that.
Indeed, I have this Java Entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer id;

 private String email;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
}
```

and my goal is to transform/map the class below into this xml format:

```
<customer>
   <id>...</id>
   <email>....</email>
   <names>
      <firstName>...</firstName>
      <lastName>...</lastName>
   <names>
</customer>
```

The problem is that I can't use @XmlElementWrapper because it is not applicable on non collection property, and I'm searching for a solution that doesn't require to create a class "names" which will contains firstname and lastname.

Comment: Do you have multiple `<names>` tag inside a `<customer>` tag?

Comment: @NitinBisht no , only one

Comment: Then you need to change your model class, add `private Name names;` and keep first name and last name inside `Name class` not in `customer class`